# Does DNA match of 1,781 cM suggest half siblings?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

I have been contacted by someone who says we are half sisters due to our DNA match. Our DNA is 1,781 which apparently is a high match.

Would this make us half sisters?

I am an only child and she is adopted.

Answer (score 2):

Another task for [DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1781)

It says possible relationships are:

- Grandparent
- Aunt / Uncle
- Half Sibling
- Niece / Nephew
- Grandchild

I'm guessing that you can rule out some/most of these.

Half-sister is quite possible for people who share 1781 cM of DNA; they usually fall between 1160 and 2436 cM, and 1781 is right in the middle of that range.